# GAE template renders form as html text rather than the form

Tags: html, google-app-engine, templates

I am working through the GoogleAppEngine Event example and I'm trying to
build a form that I can enter event data

```
from google.appengine.ext.db import djangoforms

class Event(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    description = db.TextProperty()
    time = db.DateTimeProperty()
    location = db.TextProperty()
    creator = db.UserProperty()

class EventForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event

class EventsPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        eventform = EventForm()

        if users.get_current_user():
            url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Logout'
        else:
            url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Login'

        template_values = {
            'events': events,
            'eventform': eventform,
            'url': url,
            'url_linktext': url_linktext,
        }

        template = jinja_environment.get_template('events.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

----events.html----
<html>
 <head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
 {% for event in events %}
   <blockquote>{{ event.content|escape }}</blockquote>
 {% endfor %}
 <form action="/newevent" method="post">
  <!--  Even though <table> is below, event form is not put inside <table>.  Why?? -->
  <table>
    {{ eventform|escape }}
  </table>
  <div><input type="submit" value="New Event"></div>
 </form>
 <a href="{{ url }}">{{ url_linktext }}</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run my code, the following is rendered on my page as text:

`<tr><th><label for="id_title">Title:</label></th><td><input type="text"
name="title" id="id_title" /></td></tr> <tr><th><label
for="id_description">Description:</label></th><td><textarea id="id_description"
rows="10" cols="40" name="description"></textarea></td></tr> <tr><th><label
for="id_time">Time:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="time" id="id_time"
/></td></tr> <tr><th><label
for="id_location">Location:</label></th><td><textarea id="id_location"
rows="10" cols="40" name="location"></textarea></td></tr> <tr><th><label
for="id_creator">Creator:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="creator"
id="id_creator" /></td></tr>`

I can tell this is table code and I want to the page to render as a tabular form, not as text.    Any ideas why this is happening?  And how to
make it render as a form?

Comment: Could you post the template that's used to generate this page?  It looks like the file that was served is missing the `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` boilerplate for HTML, and it's quite possible that this is because the template is missing that boilerplate too.

Comment: I added the entire template which does have `<html>` tags.  I still can't figure out why it prints the html as text but doesn't render it as a form.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with Jinja, as per Jinja2 documentation it seems to escape all HTML by default.

From looking at your template above, I see that you are using the 'escape' filter on the 'eventform', I was not able to find information about such a filter for Jinja. Also if you want the form to be rendered as a HTML form, then why would we need to escape it?

{{ eventform|escape }}

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#autoescaping